# No output from SAS Macro code (no error msg)

Tags: sas

I tried searching around for solution but none of them works for me. I had another macro code that works but this just does not work at all. There are no errors indicated in the log. And if I try to run it multiple times, i'll get 'WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long. You may have unbalanced quotation marks.' I tried to close my Chrome, run on another browser, even to the extend of restarting my computer but nope.

Could anyone help with this?
Code as following:

```
 %MACRO MACRO_BIV_CAT(DS_NAME_BIV,VARIABLE_1_BIV,VARIABLE_2_BIV,TITLE_1_BIV);

PROC FREQ DATA= &DS_NAME_BIV;
TABLE &VARIABLE_1_BIV * &VARIABLE_2_BIV /
PLOTS = FREQPLOT( TWOWAY = STACKED SCALE = GROUPPCT );
TITLE &TITLE_1_BIV;
RUN;
%MEND MACRO_BIV_CAT;

/* Call the SAS Macro for bivariate analysis on categorical variable found in Testing DS */

%MACRO_BIV_CAT((MYDAPASS.TESTINGCOPY,GENDER,EMPLOYMENT, 
'Bivariate Analysis on Gender vs Employment')
```

Output:

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         %MACRO MACRO_BIV_CAT(DS_NAME_BIV,VARIABLE_1_BIV,VARIABLE_2_BIV,TITLE_1_BIV);
 74         
 75         PROC FREQ DATA= &DS_NAME_BIV;
 76         TABLE &VARIABLE_1_BIV * &VARIABLE_2_BIV /
 77         PLOTS = FREQPLOT( TWOWAY = STACKED SCALE = GROUPPCT );
 78         TITLE &TITLE_1_BIV;
 79         RUN;
 80         %MEND MACRO_BIV_CAT;
 81         
 82         /* Call the SAS Macro for bivariate analysis on categorical variable found in Testing DS */
 83         
 84         %MACRO_BIV_CAT((MYDAPASS.TESTINGCOPY,GENDER,EMPLOYMENT,
 85         'Bivariate Analysis on Gender vs Employment')
 86         
 87         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 88         ODS HTML CLOSE;
 89         &GRAPHTERM; ;*';*";*/;RUN;QUIT;
 90         QUIT;RUN;
 91         ODS HTML5 (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
 92         
 93         ODS RTF (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
 94         ODS PDF (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
 95         FILENAME _GSFNAME;
 96         DATA _NULL_;
 97         RUN;
 98         OPTIONS NOTES STIMER SOURCE SYNTAXCHECK;
```

Comment: **I added a semicolon for the following: %MACRO_BIV_CAT((MYDAPASS.TESTINGCOPY,GENDER,EMPLOYMENT, 
'Bivariate Analysis on Gender vs Employment');                            It didnt work either.

Comment: Looks like the auto generated lines 2 to 71 probably have some mistake that is making it not work.  Can you run ANY code?  What user interface are you using that is pushing your code to SAS to run?  Enterprise Guide? Or SAS/Studio?  Either one will have an option for not hiding those auto generated lines of code.

Comment: The double open-parenthesis on line 84 might be the problem.

Comment: Yep - the extra open paren in the call will kill it in this manner.  `%MACRO_BIV_CAT((`

Comment: Thank you so much. Yep it's the open paren that is causing the issue. I didn't realize it at all. All good now!